# How i can update data firebase with specific key in golang?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

I am using golang and [firego](https://github.com/zabawaba99/firego) for connecting to Firebase. I want to update my data `Status`from ON to OFF with key `IDAgent: 7`. This is my Database Structure

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWM4J.png)

*Assumption : I don't know child active_chat. How can i update data in active_chat/-Koja8GuFplEN3kjbfPO where IDAgent = 7*

I have tried this code

```
x := map[string]string{"Status": "OFF"}
ref.OrderBy("IDAgent").EqualTo("7").Update(x)
```

but this code wrong query.

Answer (score 1):

In two ways you can do, as per [Firebase doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-update) with firego client library. Drafted answer based on from firego [README.md](https://github.com/zabawaba99/firego/blob/v1/README.md).

*Note: You have not provided the complete path of the structure, I have drafted the answer based on screenshot. So update your JSON path accordingly.*

Approach 1:

```
f := firego.New("https://my-firebase-app.firebaseIO.com/active-chat/Koja8GuFpIEN3kjbfPO.json", nil)

x := map[string]string{
   "Status": "OFF",
}
if err := f.Update(x); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Approach 2:

```
f := firego.New("https://my-firebase-app.firebaseIO.com", nil)
f = f.Ref("/active-chat/Koja8GuFpIEN3kjbfPO.json")

x := map[string]string{
   "Status": "OFF",
}
if err := f.Update(x); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: if i don't know this child (Koja8GuFpIEN3kjbfPO) how i can update in data IDAgent = 7 ?

Comment: It is not possible to update, you need to know the key path of the child object you're updating. Refer to the firebase doc I mentioned in the answer.  firego client internally sends the HTTP PATCH request with json for updating the value.

Comment: can i get key path where ID Agent = 7? or it is impossible?

Comment: Firebase data structure is typically JSON data. Via HTTP request you're accessing and manipulating. The URL Path you're using for this `ref.OrderBy("IDAgent")` object is your key path.

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2022:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    firestore "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

type (
    myDocument struct {
        Cars       []Car  `firestore:"cars"`
        carsCount  int64  `firestore:"car_count"`
        UpdateTime string `firestore:"update_time"`
    }
    Car struct {
        Name      string `firestore:"name"`
        YearBuilt string `firestore:"year_built"`
    }
)

func getFirebaseClient(ctx context.Context) (*firestore.Client, error) {
    sa := option.WithCredentialsFile("Path_To_Firebase_Key")

    // Initialize firebase app with admin privileges
    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, nil, sa)

    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("getFirestoreClient failed: %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    // Create client
    client, err := app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("failed to connect to firestore: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return client, nil
}

func main() {
    // Create context
    ctx := context.Background()

    // Get firebase client
    client, err := getFirebaseClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create car struct
    newCar := Car{
        "Volvo_Series1",
        "1920",
    }

    // Update time
    newTime := time.Now().UTC().Format("Monday, 01-02-2006 15:04:05")

    // Updates to document
    updates := []firestore.Update{
        {Path: "cars", Value: firestore.ArrayUnion(newCar)},
        {Path: "car_count", Value: firestore.Increment(1)},
        {Path: "update_date", Value: newTime},
    }

    // OPTION A)
    // Create collection reference
    collectionRef := client.Collection("cars")

    // Create document reference
    docRef := collectionRef.Doc("12345")

    // Update document
    _, err = docRef.Update(ctx, updates)
    if err != nil {
        err := fmt.Errorf("failed updating document: %s from %s collection %v", docRef.ID, docRef.Parent.ID, err)
        panic(err)
    }

    // OPTION B)
    _, err = client.Collection("cars").Doc("12345").Update(ctx, updates)
    if err != nil {
        err := fmt.Errorf("failed updating document: %s from %s collection %v", docRef.ID, docRef.Parent.ID, err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a link to the documentation to make this answer more complete: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#hdr-Reading